# Easier proof of "countable hypocompactness"

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

I am interested in the following result, which appears as an old qual problem:

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $\{U_i\}$ a countable open cover. Prove that there exists a countable open refinement $\{V_j\}$ such that for each $j$, we have $V_j\cap V_k\neq\emptyset$ for at most finitely many $k$.

In the literature, such refinements are called *star-finite*, and spaces with this property are called "countably hypocompact," although this language does not appear to be standard. I have proven the result more generally for paracompact Hausdorff spaces; but the proof (essentially due to Morita) is rather ungainly and seems too involved to be expected on a qualifying exam. It requires constructing a countable closed refinement of the original cover and performing a slightly intricate construction using Urysohn functions.

My question is this: is there a more direct proof in the case that $X$ is a metric space? I am tempted to exploit the existence of partitions of unity subordinate to the original cover, but alas star-finiteness is a stronger property than local finiteness (or point-finiteness, for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$There’s a fairly short but somewhat tricky proof for countably paracompact normal spaces. Let $X$ be such a space, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable open cover of $X$. $X$ is countably paracompact, so $\mathscr{U}$ has a locally finite open refinement $\mathscr{R}$. For each $R\in\mathscr{R}$ choose $n(R)\in\Bbb N$ such that $R\subseteq U_{n(R)}$, and for $k\in\Bbb N$ let $V_k=\bigcup\{R\in\mathscr{R}:n(R)=k\}$; then $\mathscr{V}=\{V_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ is a locally finite open refinement of $\mathscr{U}$ such that $V_k\subseteq U_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$.

Let $F_0=V_0\setminus\bigcup_{k>0}V_k$; $F_0$ is a closed subset of $V_0$, and $X$ is normal, so there is an open $W_0$ such that $F_0\subseteq W_0\subseteq\cl W_0\subseteq V_0$. Note that $\{W_0\}\cup\{V_k:k>0\}$ covers $X$. Suppose that $k>0$, and we have open sets $W_i$ for $i<k$ such that $\{W_i:i<k\}\cup\{V_i:i\ge k\}$ covers $X$, and $\cl W_i\subseteq V_i$ for each $i<k$. Let

$$F_k=V_k\setminus\left(\bigcup_{i<k}W_i\cup\bigcup_{i>k}V_i\right)\;;$$

$F_k$ is a closed subset of $V_k$, so there is an open $W_k$ such that $F_k\subseteq W_k\subseteq\cl W_k\subseteq V_k$. Clearly $\{W_i:i\le k\}\cup\{V_i:i>k\}$ covers $X$ so the construction goes through to give us a family $\mathscr{W}=\{W_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ of open sets such that $\cl W_k\subseteq V_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Clearly $\mathscr{W}$ is locally finite, and the constructions ensures that it covers $X$.

> On a qual one might be able simply to appeal to the very standard result that every point finite open cover of a normal space is shrinkable and avoid the construction of the previous paragraph. However, the real work is yet to come.

For $k\in\Bbb N$ let $W_k^*=\bigcup_{i\le k}W_i$ and $V_k^*=\bigcup_{i\le k}V_i$, and note that $\cl W_k^*\subseteq V_k^*$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. By normality there are open sets $G_{k,\ell}$ for $k,\ell\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$\cl W_k^*\subset G_{k,\ell}\subseteq\cl G_{k,\ell}\subseteq G_{k,\ell+1}\subseteq V_k^*$$

for all $k,\ell\in\Bbb N$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $H_n=\bigcup\{G_{k,\ell}:k+\ell=n\}$; clearly $\{H_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an open cover of $X$. Moreover, the construction ensures that $\cl H_n\subseteq H_{n+1}\subseteq V_n^*$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$: if $k+\ell=n$, then $\cl G_{k,\ell}\subseteq G_{k,\ell+1}\subseteq H_{n+1}\cap V_k^*\subseteq V_n^*$.

Let $B_0=H_0$ and $B_1=H_1$, and for $n\ge 2$ let $B_n=H_n\setminus\cl H_{n-2}$. Clearly each $B_n$ is open, and $B_n\subseteq H_n\subseteq V_n^*$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. For $n\ge 2$ we have $\cl H_{n-2}\subseteq H_{n-1}$ and hence $$B_n=H_n\setminus\cl H_{n-2}\supseteq H_n\setminus H_{n-1}\;.$$ Checking the case $n=1$ separately, we see that in fact

$$H_n\setminus H_{n-1}\subseteq B_n\subseteq V_n^*$$

for all $n\ge 1$, and of course $H_0=B_0\subseteq V_0=V_0^*$, so $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ covers $X$.

Finally, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and $k\le n$ let $B_n(k)=B_n\cap V_k$, and let $$\mathscr{B}=\{B_n(k):k,n\in\Bbb N\text{ and }k\le n\}\;.$$

$B_n\subseteq V_n^*$, so $B_n=\bigcup_{k\le n}B_n(k)$, and $\bigcup\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n=X$, so $\mathscr{B}$ is an open cover of $X$. Evidently $\mathscr{B}$ refines $\mathscr{V}$ and hence $\mathscr{U}$, so it only remains to show that $\mathscr{B}$ is star-finite.

Fix $B_n(k)\in\mathscr{B}$; $B_n(k)\subseteq B_n\subseteq H_n$. If $m\ge n+2$, then $B_m=H_m\setminus\cl H_{m-2}\subseteq H_m\setminus H_n$, and $B_n(k)\cap B_m=\varnothing$. Thus, if $B_n(k)\cap B_m(\ell)\ne\varnothing$, then $\ell\le m\le n+1$, and we’re done.

I don’t at the moment see any way to use metrizability to simplify this. (This argument, by the way, is due to Kiyoshi Iséki in the short paper [‘A Note on Countably Paracompact Spaces’](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195526077), Proc. Japan Acad. $30$ ($1954$), no. $5$, $350$-$351$.)